# Bitmap bounds could not be determined. If bitmap is loaded, it won't be scaled

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

Hi i am getting error  in titanium when i move from one window to another and back to first.
first window conatins a png image. would like to know how to remove this error thx.

**Code:**

```
var noteview = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        image : 'TaskNote.png',
        width : '10%',
        left : '70%',
        height:'70%',
        labelname:'Note'

    });

noteview.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    var tasknotewindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor : 'white',
        layout : 'vertical',
        url : 'TimeTracker/tasknote.js'

    });

   tasknotewindow.starttime=inlabel.text;

    tasknotewindow.open();


});
```

**Error:**

> 01-08 12:37:42.111: W/TiDrawableReference(501): (main) [295,31932]
>   Bitmap bounds could not be determined. If bitmap is loaded, it won't
>   be scaled.

Comment: Please paste your code and error. Let's see what you've done

Comment: Can you please show us the error?

Comment: Error::  01-08 12:37:42.111: W/TiDrawableReference(501): (main) [295,31932] Bitmap bounds could not be determined. If bitmap is loaded, it won't be scaled.

Comment: Try to use `backgroundImage` property instead of `image`.

Comment: Aditya, Can you add more code, i mean how you moves between the windows. May be that will be more descriptive.